# Google Authenticator: Why does the backup code contain unallowed characters?

Tags: restore, google-authenticator

I want to restore my Google Authenticator entries but it's not allowed to enter the characters '8' and '9'.

Is there a solution?

Thanks for help!

Comment: A screenshot would help. It's not clear